# UITableView lag when scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, lag

I use a tableView , manually cached cells , but when I scroll I get a little lag .
This is my code :

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{


    var realRow = indexPath.row / 2
    if indexPath.row / 2 > self.SUGGESTED_USERS_RATE && suggestedUsers.count > 0
    {
        --realRow
    }
    if indexPath.row / 2 > self.SUGGESTED_RADIOS_RATE && suggestedRadioStations.count > 0
    {
        --realRow
    }

    if indexPath.row % 2 == 1
    {
        return self.CELL_MARGIN
    }
    else if indexPath.row / 2 == self.SUGGESTED_USERS_RATE && suggestedUsers.count > 0
    {
        return self.SUGGESTED_USERS_CELL_HEIGHT
    }
    else if indexPath.row / 2 == self.SUGGESTED_RADIOS_RATE && suggestedRadioStations.count > 0
    {
        return self.SUGGESTED_USERS_CELL_HEIGHT
    }
    else
    {
        return self.CELLS_HEIGHT[realRow]//[indexPath.row / 2 - indexPath.row / (self.SUGGESTED_USERS_RATE * 2 + 2)]
    }
```

//            let row = indexPath.row / 2

```
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var realRow = indexPath.row / 2

    if indexPath.row / 2 > self.SUGGESTED_USERS_RATE && suggestedUsers.count > 0
    {
        --realRow
    }
    if indexPath.row / 2 > self.SUGGESTED_RADIOS_RATE && suggestedRadioStations.count > 0
    {
        --realRow
    }




    if indexPath.row % 2 == 1
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "")
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3)

        cell.selectionStyle = .None

        addSeperatorsToView(cell.contentView, width: self.bounds.width,
            height: self.CELL_MARGIN, up: true, down: true, left: false, right: false)

        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row / 2 == self.SUGGESTED_RADIOS_RATE && suggestedRadioStations.count > 0
    {
        let cell = SuggestedUsersCell(width: self.bounds.width, height: self.SUGGESTED_USERS_CELL_HEIGHT, radios: suggestedRadioStations.prefix(5) + [])
        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row / 2 == self.SUGGESTED_USERS_RATE && suggestedUsers.count > 0
    {
        let cell = SuggestedUsersCell(width: self.bounds.width, height: self.SUGGESTED_USERS_CELL_HEIGHT, users: suggestedUsers.prefix(5)  + [])
        return cell
    }
    else
    {
        var cell : ActivityTableViewCell

        if let myCell = self.cells_cache[realRow]
        {
            cell = myCell
        }
        else
        {
            let activity = self.actevetiesArr[realRow]

            cell = ActivityTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: self.CELL_ID,
                height: self.CELLS_HEIGHT[realRow],
                width: self.bounds.width, activity: activity ,
                index : realRow  ,
                delegate : self)

            self.cells_cache[realRow] = cell

        }



        cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
        cell.selectionStyle = .None

        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    var count = self.actevetiesArr.count * 2

    if self.actevetiesArr.count > self.SUGGESTED_USERS_RATE
    {
        count = count + 2
    }
    if self.actevetiesArr.count > self.SUGGESTED_RADIOS_RATE
    {
        count = count + 2
    }

    if self.actevetiesArr.count < max(self.SUGGESTED_USERS_RATE , self.SUGGESTED_RADIOS_RATE)
    {
        count += 2
        self.SUGGESTED_RADIOS_RATE = 1
        self.SUGGESTED_USERS_RATE = 0
    }
    else
    {
        self.SUGGESTED_USERS_RATE = SUGGESTED_USERS_INDEX
        self.SUGGESTED_RADIOS_RATE = SUGGESTED_RADIOS_INDEX
    }

    if suggestedRadioStations.count == 0
    {
        count -= 2
    }

    if suggestedUsers.count == 0
    {
        count -= 2
    }

    return count//(self.actevetiesArr.count + (self.actevetiesArr.count 
}
```

what is the problem ??! , I don't do a huge amount of code in cellForRowAtIndexPath.
Note : cell_cache is a dictionary ==> [Int:  ActivityTableViewCell

Comment: Use Instruments to find out what part of your code causes the lag.

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/a/35868056/2963912

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return  44;
}
```

or you can add

`self.tableView. estimatedRowHeight = 44.0` in `viewDidLoad`

let me know if it works

Comment: It should work. This delegate definitely improves table view scroll performance.

Comment: Alternatively, put `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0` in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are not using the idiomatic way - i.e. you should use reusable cells.

Comment: I cannot use reusable cells because there's a lot kinds of cells, my solution was to save them by the dictionary

Comment: You have no choice. You have to organise your cells properly and reuse them. It's not a problem if you will have 10-15 different custom cells and register them ALL :)

Comment: There is really no excuse of not using tableView's cell reuse mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Try to user reuseable cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
       cell = (CustomCell *) [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
       cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I cannot use reusable cells because there's a lot kinds of cells, my solution was to save them by the dictionary

Comment: Then rethink your design. If you want performance, reusable cells are the way to go.